# so i have this code, but some part of it cant work well

Tags: c

so the broken part is in the Level Requirement, can you help me to solve it ?
so the level requirement is S needs 80, A needs 60, B needs 40, C needs 20, D needs 10, E needs 2.
and the code must uses struct
and i think the wrong part is in the struct it self.
thanks (just dont read the rest)

so the broken part is in the Level Requirement, can you help me to solve it ?
so the level requirement is S needs 80, A needs 60, B needs 40, C needs 20, D needs 10, E needs 2.
and the code must uses struct
and i think the wrong part is in the struct it self.
so the broken part is in the Level Requirement, can you help me to solve it ?
so the level requirement is S needs 80, A needs 60, B needs 40, C needs 20, D needs 10, E needs 2.
and the code must uses struct
and i think the wrong part is in the struct it self.
so the broken part is in the Level Requirement, can you help me to solve it ?
so the level requirement is S needs 80, A needs 60, B needs 40, C needs 20, D needs 10, E needs 2.
and the code must uses struct
and i think the wrong part is in the struct it self.
so the broken part is in the Level Requirement, can you help me to solve it ?
so the level requirement is S needs 80, A needs 60, B needs 40, C needs 20, D needs 10, E needs 2.
and the code must uses struct
and i think the wrong part is in the struct it self.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

struct Hero
{
   char nama[50];
   int level;
   char job[10];
};

struct Quest
{
   char nama[100];
   int reward;
   char ranking[2];
};

int main()
{
   int pilih,jhero=1,jquest=1;
   struct Hero hiro[10];
   struct Quest questo[10];
   do
   {
       system("cls");
       printf("============================================\n");
       printf("                 HERO GUILD\n");
       printf("============================================\n");
       printf("1. Member Registration\n");
       printf("2. Post a quest\n");
       printf("3. Show all member\n");
       printf("4. Show all quest\n");
       printf("0. Exit\n");
       printf("Input : ");
       scanf("%d",&pilih);
       fflush(stdin);
       switch(pilih)
       {
       case 2 :
           system("cls");
           printf("============================================\n");
           printf("         HERO GUILD - POST A QUEST\n");
           printf("============================================\n");
           printf("Title : "); gets(questo[jquest].nama);fflush(stdin);
           printf("Reward <$>:       ");scanf("%d",&questo[jquest].reward);fflush(stdin);
           printf("Rank :    ");scanf("%s",questo[jquest].ranking);fflush(stdin);
           jquest++;
           printf("Press Any Key To Continue...");
           getch();
           break;
       case 4 :
           system("cls");
           int j;
           printf("============================================\n");
           printf("             HERO GUILD - QUEST\n");
           printf("============================================\n");
           for(j=1;j<jquest;j++)
           {
               printf("Quest-%d\n",j);
               printf("Title\t: %s\n",questo[j].nama);
               printf("Reward\t: %d\n",questo[j].reward);
               printf("Rank\t: %s\n",questo[j].ranking);
               printf("Level Requirement : >= ");
               /*switch(questo[j].ranking)
               {
               case 'S' :printf("80\n\n");break;
               case 'A' :printf("60\n\n");break;
               case 'B' :printf("40\n\n");break;
               case 'C' :printf("20\n\n");break;
               case 'D' :printf("10\n\n");break;
               case 'E' :printf("2\n\n");break;
               }*/
           }
           printf("Press Any Key To Continue...");
           getch();
           break;
       case 0 : return 0;
       }
   }while(1);
 }
```

Comment: Never *ever* use `gets`. It's a dangerous function which are prone to buffer overflows, and has therefore been removed from the C language. Use e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead. Also, passing an input-only streak (like `stdin`) to `fflush` is explicitly undefined behavior according to the C specification.

Comment: As for your problem, do you mean you enter two digits for the `ranking`? Why read it as a string if its a number? And remember that `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings. That *null-terminator* also needs space. A string of two characters needs space for *three* to include the terminator.

Comment: no, i just want to put 'S' or else to the level requirement and automaticly the program will know the level of the requirement

Comment: Then you should probably read a *character* instead of a string. That will make your out-commented `switch` statement work as well. Which maybe was your problem?

Comment: this part

switch(questo[j].ranking)
               {
               case 'S' :printf("80\n\n");break;
               case 'A' :printf("60\n\n");break;
               case 'B' :printf("40\n\n");break;
               case 'C' :printf("20\n\n");break;
               case 'D' :printf("10\n\n");break;
               case 'E' :printf("2\n\n");break;
               }

Comment: What ***is*** `questo[j].ranking`? What is (e.g.) `'S'`? Are those the same *type*?

Comment: maybe, but i think that the wrong part. is that the right syntax ???

Comment: nevermind, i use strcmp and it's work.
thanks Some programmer dude
and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ranking` member is supposed to be a single `char`, so declare it as such and then read it as such and use it as such:

```
// ...

struct Quest
{
   char nama[100];
   int reward;
   char ranking;  // Single-character rank
};

// ...

scanf(" %c", &questo[j].ranking);  // Leading space to skip initial white-space
// TODO: Should really check what scanf returns

// ...

printf("Rank\t: %c\n",questo[j].ranking);

// ...

switch (questo[j].ranking)
{
case 'S':
    // ...

default:
    // TODO: Handle the case if the rank is incorrect
    break;
}

// ...
```

Comment: @AlexWibisono You're welcome. Now please take some time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)